# Induction, coinduction, and ordinal induction

Tags: induction, ordinals, transfinite-induction

As a computer scientists, I have been thought to use induction and coinduction principles for proving properties of finite and infinite structures, respectively.

When does one use ordinal induction? Since it is still *induction*, one cannot replace coinduction with ordinal one? In which cases one could not use induction and coinduction, and would have to resort to ordinal induction? How do these induction principles relate?

Formal and informal explanations are both welcomed.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by coinduction? Anyway, we can do induction whenever we have a well-ordered (or well-founded) set to work on.

Comment: @Tobias: I haven’t time right now to take a close look, but [this PDF](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~kozen/papers/Structural.pdf) seems to be a good starting point, both for what coinduction is and for why/how it works.